# Drupal6: problem with exposed filters in Views2

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

i'm trying to create a View in Drupal6; i would like to have a single textfield to be used as filter; i've defined an exposed filter of type search term and it runs fine when the user enters the correct string; i would like to show results also in case of substring (using the LIKE operator) but i cannot see how to define it in search term.
Do i have to override sql string in a form_alter? If so, how can i do it?

Thanks in advance and greetings
c.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the Contains operator.

Comment: yes, but i don't see the contains operator in Search Term ... contains operator is present only in other fields

Comment: @Cris: The search term filter uses core search which only finds exact matches. Hence no Contains operator. You can install a contributed stemming or n-gram module to modify this behavior. Or you use other filters, e.g. Node:Body.